# Python quicksort - one list - swaps

Tags: python, list, recursion, quicksort

****I need to make a quicksort algorithm but so that it uses only one list and does swaps inside of it. I managed to make it "sort" or position the first element but now i don't know how to implement the recursion. The biggest problem I'm having is how to recursively work on a part of the list instead of making the new one. Here is my code:**
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------**
New code, same problem.

Here is my code. It does the job but gets stuck in the loop.

```
def qsort(n,l,g):
if l is None:
    l=0
if g is None:
    g=len(n)
if g-l<=1:
    return n
print g-l
p=n[l]
i=1+l
j=1+l
for x in n[l+1:g]:
    if x<p:
        n[i],n[j]=n[j],n[i]
        i+=1
    j+=1
n[l],n[i-1]=n[i-1],n[l]
ls=0
le=i-1
gs=i
ge=j
print n
qsort(n,ls,le)
qsort(n,gs,ge)
```

Can someone give me any suggestions, I'm lost. Can't find whats wrong or how to fix it.
Know its messy but cant do better atm :D

Comment: What returns? You need them to return the values

Comment: Make an auxiliary recursive function that takes the whole list, start and end points (and maybe pivot or something; I don't quite remember how quicksort works), and then call that auxiliary function from the main function.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the following link?
http://en.literateprograms.org/Quicksort_(Python)

It has recursive qsort in python

Comment: @TheOneWhoPrograms I've had a look and that's a really bad link. `pop` instead of a `for` loop; `+` to prepend to a list (where they should just `.append` for speed), etc. Bad practices everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write it like this:

```
def qsort(li, lo=None, hi=None):
    if lo is None:
        lo = 0
    if hi is None:
        hi = len(li) - 1
    ...
    ...
    if hi - lo > 1:
        qsort(## left half ##)
        qsort(## right half ##)
```

`lo` and `hi` are the smallest and largest indexes you should look at in `li`, respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the posts guys. I see now what u and Istvan are thinking of and ill be back with more questions soon if i fail to implement it :D

Answer (score 0):

Swap version of quicksort.

`quicksort([10, 0, 9, 1, 8, 2, 7, 3, 6, 4, 5]) >> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

`quicksort([0, 4, 2, 3, 6]) >> [0, 2, 3, 4, 6]`

```
def quicksort(seq):
    if len(seq) <= 1:
        return seq
    pivot_index = len(seq)-1
    i = 0
    while i < pivot_index:
        if seq[i] > seq[pivot_index] and pivot_index-1 == i:
            seq[i], seq[pivot_index] = seq[pivot_index], seq[i]
            pivot_index -= 1
            i = 0
        elif seq[i] > seq[pivot_index] and pivot_index > 1:
            seq[pivot_index-1], seq[pivot_index] = seq[pivot_index], seq[pivot_index-1]
            seq[i], seq[pivot_index] = seq[pivot_index], seq[i]
            pivot_index -= 1
            i = 0
        else:
            i += 1
    return quicksort(seq[:pivot_index]) + [seq[pivot_index]] + quicksort(seq[pivot_index+1:])
```